# Highcharts: Using an array as a data series - ordering

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am creating a stacked column chart, and really just testing highcharts out. I would like to hear how people suggest solving the following case:

In a stacked column chart, I would need the following example code:

```
series: [
  { name:'seed', data: [12, 8, 9]}, 
  { name:'predicted', data: [121, 88, 97]} 
],
xAxis: {
  categories: ['tech', 'sport', 'finance']
},
```

This means that a single object in my db :

```
{ category: 'tech', seed: 12, predicted: 121 }
```

Needs to be split into two arrays which could introduce ordering bugs.

Is there no way to pass objects to `highcharts` and then manipulate them with some `options`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you wary of depending solely on the *order* of elements in the `data` array for determining which category the elements belong to?

If so, I think the [`xAxis.type`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.type) option might interest you:

```
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category'
  },
  series: [{
      name: 'tech',
      data: [{name:"seed", y:12}, {name:"predicted", y:121}]
    }, {
      name: 'sport',
      data: [{name:"seed", y:8}, {name:"predicted", y:88}]
    }, {
      name: 'finance',
      data: [{name:"predicted", y:97}, {name:"seed", y:9}]
    }
  ]
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/ub2gwq61/

---

From [Highcharts API Reference](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/)

> In a category axis, the **point** of the chart's series are used for
>   categories, if not a **categories** array is defined.